# Вывод определенной записи

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть 100 записей. Как вывести записи я знаю, но как вывести актуальную на первое место к пример запись с id 55, а дальше по плану 1,2,3 и т.д

Comment: Получите одну, а потом вторым запросом все остальные.

Comment: Интересует именно одним запросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним запросом можно сделать так:

```
select * from mytbl order by id = 55 desc, id asc;
```